# VBA throwing 'else without if' error

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I was trying out the following code and its repeatedly throwing the 'else without if' and such similar errors. I just cant figure out where the error lies, because each if is properly terminated.

Here is the code:

```
Sub hra_macro()

Dim city As Boolean
Dim salary As Integer
Dim varHRA As Integer
Dim mimHRA As Integer
Dim maxHRA As Integer
Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer
Dim Rent As Integer

city = Range("b1").Value
salary = Range("b2").Value
Rent = Range("b3").Value

If city = True Then

varHRA = 0

    A = Rent - (salary / 10)
    B = salary * 0.5
    Do While varHRA < salary
        varHRA = varHRA + 1
            If (varHRA < A And varHRA < B) Then
            minHRA = varHRA
            End If
            If (A < varHRA And A < B) Then
            minHRA = A
            End If
            If (B < varHRA And B < A) Then
            minHRA = B
            End If
            If minHRA > maxHRA Then
            maxHRA = minHRA
            End If
    Exit Do
Else '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< PROBLEM AREA

varHRA = 0

    A = Rent - (salary / 10)
    B = salary * 0.4
    Do While varHRA < salary
        varHRA = varHRA + 1
        If (varHRA < A And varHRA < B) Then
        minHRA = varHRA
        End If
        If (A < varHRA And A < B) Then
        minHRA = A
        End If
        If (B < varHRA And B < A) Then
        minHRA = B
        End If
    If minHRA > maxHRA Then
    maxHRA = minHRA
    End If
    Exit Do
End If

Range("b4").Value = maxHRA

End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button. I have done it for you this time.

Comment: Thank you. This is the first time i'm using the site. Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `If`s look okay to me at first glance, but I noticed that both `Do`s are missing the `Loop`.

It should look like this:

```
Do While varHRA < salary
    'Do Stuff
Loop
```

`Exit Do` is used to exit the loop before the condition behind the `While` is true, but you always need the `Loop` keyword.

If the problem still remains, please post the exact error message that you're getting.

---

*EDIT:*

I just tried to reproduce your problem in VBA in MS Access (I don't have Excel installed on this machine, only Access):

```
Public Function Test()

    If 1 = 0 Then

        Do While 1 = 0

            Stop

        Exit Do

    Else

        Stop

    End If

End Function
```

This simple piece of code gives me the exact same error message that you got:

> Compile error: Else without If

When I replace the `Exit Do` by a `Loop`, the error goes away and the code compiles.

So, you should replace the `Exit Do` by `Loop` in your code.

Comment: Hello sir, The exact message is 'Compile error: Else without If'.

Comment: @Chinmay Kamat: Even if your error message says nothing about the `Loop`, this seems to cause the error. Read my answer again, I added an example.

Comment: This is definitely the answer, I have also tested and in Excel.

Comment: @ChinmayKamat: If my answer was helpful, it would be nice if you accept it as the right one (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your using 'Exit Do' instead of 'Loop'.  'Exit Do' will exit the Do loop, is this the way you want this to behave?

Comment: Yes i wanted it to happen that way. Is that the problem?

Comment: @Chinmay Kamat: Are you really sure you want it to happen that way? If you put `Exit Do` in the loop without some kind of condition, it will **completely exit the loop**. So it doesn't loop at all, it just executes the code after the `Do` exactly one time until it hits the `Exit Do`.